# Spring Boot (Microservices) Gateway fails on authentication with JWT

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have built a micro service gateway with Spring Boot Gateway and it works. Next I added security, but I cannot make gateway forward authentication request to authenticator microservice. **How to forward request to authenticator micro service?** As I understand request fails in gateway. Here I describe what I did and source codes are on git:

https://github.com/pavelmorozov/SpringBootGateway, https://github.com/pavelmorozov/EurekaServer, 
https://github.com/pavelmorozov/ConfigMicroService, https://github.com/pavelmorozov/AuthenticatorMicroService

Here the request auth.sh I use to authenticate

```
user="omar"
pass="12345"

generate_post_data()
{
cat <<EOF
{
    "username": "$user",
    "password": "$pass"
}
EOF
}

echo $(generate_post_data)

echo "======================"
echo "http://localhost:8060/auth"
echo "======================"

# -v verbose
curl -v -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: POST' \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    "http://localhost:8060/auth/" \
    -d "$(generate_post_data)"

echo
```

and it outputs to console:

```
{ "username": "omar", "password": "12345" }
======================
http://localhost:8060/auth
======================
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8060 (#0)
> POST /auth/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8060
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 45
> 
* upload completely sent off: 45 out of 45 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 403 
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< X-XSS-Protection: 1 ; mode=block
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Tue, 25 Sep 2018 18:52:33 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
CSRF Token has been associated to this client
```

I tried to put break points and get where is the problem in both gateway and authenticator, but it not helps, as any breakpoints in my application classes not executed. Only when I set logs to debug I found in logs an exception:

```
2018-09-25 21:52:33 DEBUG [-,,,] Error parsing HTTP request header
java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1289) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1223) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:368) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:684) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:60) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
```

I do not understand what this exception could really mean, and I found a lot of people get same exception but it could be thrown in different cases.

To build the gateway I mostly follow the guide on https://medium.com/omarelgabrys-blog/microservices-with-spring-boot-authentication-with-jwt-part-3-fafc9d7187e8

There used Zuul but not Spring cloud gateway, though as I have my gateway worked before, and know how to build routes it should be fine. Just one thing in ZUUL config , I not found what to do with is:

```
# Exclude authorization from sensitive headers
zuul.routes.auth-service.sensitive-headers=Cookie,Set-Cookie
```

**Update** Added debug log. It contains application load and one curl call described on top of this post. **Caution!** file size more than 1 mb

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pavelmorozov/SpringBootGateway/master/doc/debug.log

**Update** I tried to simplify gateway, to catch where problem is. I commented out `spring-boot-starter-security` dependency and security classes, also I have to comment out `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` dependency. And gateway works. Once I import Tomcat with maven I got an error on request:

```
2018-09-26 13:57:07 -ERROR Failed to handle request [GET http://localhost:8060/banquet/api/event/getThemes]
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DefaultDataBufferFactory cannot be cast to org.springframework.core.io.buffer.NettyDataBufferFactory
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyWriteResponseFilter.lambda$filter$0(NettyWriteResponseFilter.java:71) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-core-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:45) [reactor-core-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:153) ~[reactor-core-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.ignoreDone(MonoIgnoreThen.java:190) ~[reactor-core-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreInner.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:239) ~[reactor-core-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:1121) ~[reactor-core-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenAcceptInner.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:313) ~[reactor-core-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:128) [reactor-core-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoEmpty.subscribe(MonoEmpty.java:45) ~[reactor-core-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53) [reactor-core-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53) [reactor-core-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:153) ~[reactor-core-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.ignoreDone(MonoIgnoreThen.java:190) ~[reactor-core-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreInner.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:239) ~[reactor-core-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:245) ~[reactor-core-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:130) ~[reactor-core-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryPredicate$RetryPredicateSubscriber.onComplete(FluxRetryPredicate.java:107) ~[reactor-core-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.success(MonoCreate.java:147) ~[reactor-core-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.PooledClientContextHandler.fireContextActive(PooledClientContextHandler.java:87) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.9.RELEASE.jar:0.7.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:584) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.9.RELEASE.jar:0.7.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:138) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.9.RELEASE.jar:0.7.9.RELEASE]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:438) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310) ~[netty-codec-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:297) ~[netty-codec-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:413) ~[netty-codec-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265) ~[netty-codec-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:253) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.channelRead(LoggingHandler.java:241) ~[netty-handler-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:808) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.29.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:410) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.29.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:310) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.29.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884) ~[netty-common-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
```

And after that I found the thread, which seems like say TomCat incompatible with spring-cloud-gateway https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/145

Then this makes leads to be impossible spring-cloud-gateway to work with Spring Security either, because of OncePerRequest filter method description needs HTTPServletRequest, HttpServletResponse and I import TomCat to have them in class path

```
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
```

**Update** Actually Spring Security seems to be possible to use with Spring Cloud Gateway, but it should be configured in reactive manner.

Comment: I was unable to solve the problem by just reading the code. Maybe I'll debug it later. Why don't you include your own debug log messages?

Comment: Hello, I just added it - see update. I not did this initially as it quite large.

Answer (score 1):

New Spring Cloud [Greendwich.SR5](https://spring.io/blog/2020/02/01/spring-cloud-greenwich-service-release-5-sr5-is-available) release provides a new property for defining the maximum header size in the Gateway.

`spring.cloud.gateway.httpclient.maxHeaderSize`

With that you will be able to modify the http response header size.

Here you have the commit with the changes: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/commit/64a579d68d3be975a72e639c7cc123a756e21a28